# Перестала работать GPO Сопоставление дисков

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, group-policy

Контролер домена Win 2008.
GPO Настроено "Сопоставление дисков", для пользователя вошедшего, исправно работало, на любых виндах.
В какой-то момент перестало. Причем pgresult пишет что политика применена и все ок. eventvwr тоже говорит что все применено. Однако в проводнике диски не появляются. Пробовал давать доступ на работу с 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Extension-List
И
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\\Extension-List

но диски так и не появляются. Вот такая печаль.

Нашел закономерность, оказалось не монтируется файловая шара. Доступ к ней есть и с той машины на которой не отрабатывает политика. в ручную на клиентской машине тоже можно примонтировать через cmd. время отработки расширения Group Policy Drive Map 285 мс.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, оказалось две беды,-

Первая, я переименовал "подразделение", а GPO было с нацеливанием и в этом нацеливании "подразделение" не переименовалась. Как результат просто объект нацеливания не был обнаружен.
Второе наблюдается медленное соединение по сети с доменом. Чтобы устранить возможные неисправности сделал следующее:

- Конфигурация компьютера

  - Административные шаблоны

    - Система/Вход в систему

      - Всегда ждать сеть при запуске и входе в систему
      - Включено
    - Система/Групповая политика

      - Настроить обработку политики расширения предпочтений «Сопоставления дисков»

        - Включено

          - Разрешить обработку через медленное сетевое подключение
          - Включено
          - Обрабатывать, даже если объекты групповой политики не изменились
          - Включено
          - Фоновый приоритет
          - Простаивает
      - Указать время ожидания при обработке политики загрузки Включено

        - Время ожидания (в секундах): 120